# Make web application secure

Tags: php, security

I wanted to make a new php web application and if I follow the following things,
it my site then safe?

- Escape user input ($_GET && $_POST) with addslashes
- Make prepared statements with PDO
- Check user input for the right type (e.g. int or string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Security is not something that can be bolted on - it's a constant process of improvement.

- Using `addslashes` will not help you - you need to be escaping the output with `htmlentities`.
- Using prepared statement with PDO is good.
- Checking the user input for type is not enough - you need to check it way better. If you expect an email adress check for it, don't assume that if you've got a string it fine.

There are many more things to consider for security like [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)...

If you can get the book [The Web Application Hacker's Handbook: Discovering and Exploiting Security Flaws](http://bit.ly/aPuDxX). It's full of useful advices.

And, I'll say it again - security is not a feature - it's a measurement. There is not 100% secure application (or anything actually). The assumption of security is to make breaking it more expensive than what's behind it - if your site is dealing with money - you need more security - if you are dealing with giftcards - you might get away even without doing the things you suggested (which will be a very bad idea, but still).

Comment: Posting links to free information is more helpful.   This is a fairly generic question.

Comment: Why use bitly for your link.  It makes it impossible to tell where the link is going to send me.

Comment: Oh, I see. It was so you could put  your own link code into the bit.ly link.  sneaky:)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is a lot that can go wrong with web application secuirty.   I recommend reading the [OWASP Top 10](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007).  Also,  make sure to read #5 XSRF.

"escaping" input doesn't say very much.  Data can be used in many different insecure ways.  For instance the best way to prevent xss for PHP is:

```
htmlspecialchars($_GET['var'],ENT_QUOTES);
```

A good way to prevent sql injection for msyql is:

```
mysql_query("select * from mysql.user where id='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'");
```

Make sure you put the quote marks around all variables,  or the query will be vulnerable to sql injection.   But a more bullet proof approach is using parametrized queries (adodb, pdo...).  But xss and sql injection is only the tip of the ice burg,  a whole lot more can go wrong with php.  I recommend reading the FREE paper [A Study in Scarlet](http://www.securereality.com.au/studyinscarlet.txt) for specifically PHP security pitfalls.